# Virtualbox - Access guest Fedora apache server from host windows 8

Tags: virtualbox, apache-http-server, fedora-20

Arrgh please help with this

HOST: Windows 8.1 x64

GUEST: Fedora APache server

Problem: I cannot access the guest webserver through the browser on my host (using `http://192.168.2.12`), I just get page not found after about 10 seconds.

1. HOST Set virtualbox network as shared
2. GUEST Got IP address from apache 192.168.2.12 (this is the same subnet as host)
3. HOST turned off windows firewall completely
4. HOST ping guest `192.168.2.12` SUCCESS
5. GUEST browser - index.html and phpinfo on guest machine SUCCESS
6. HOST added IP to host file
7. GUEST check iptables for deny access (it's dead)

What else can I try?

Comment: I'm guessing both of you are the same user - could you take ownership of the question by requesting an account merger using the 'contact us' option?

Answer (score 1):

It was fedora firewall

```
systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

That's 6 hours wasted :(